# Session in .NET Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I want to use Session in ASP.NET MVC CORE 1.1 but a bit confused.

What is the difference between:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); vs services.AddMemoryCache();
```

It also looks like Session works without both of them, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**services.AddMemoryCache();**

which represents a cache stored in the memory of the local web server.

**services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();**

which represents a cache shared by multiple app servers. The information in the cache is not stored in the memory of individual web servers, and the cached data is available to all of the app's servers. In this, you can configure both Redis and SQL Server distributed caches.

For more info, refer these links-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed

Comment: What if I want the session to only store in client's browser?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can configure session cookie like this- `services.AddSession(opts =>  
    {
        opts.CookieName = ".MySession.Session";
        opts.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    });`

Comment: If I only want to store values in client's browser, does that mean I won't need services.AddMemoryCache() etc but will only need services.AddSession(....)?

Comment: I never tried without cache. As per docs - `Session must be configured in your application's Startup class. Session is built on top of IDistributedCache, so you must configure this as well, otherwise you will receive an error.`